# Pandas Adding column in dataframe from from another dataframe causing error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am having a dataframe df1 and df2

df1=

```
|carno | sales |
|------|------ |
|101   |   1   |
|102   |   2   |
|103   |   6   |
|101   |   8   |
```

df2 =

```
|jeepno| jsales|
|------|-------|
|107   |    3  |
|108   |    9  |
```

I want to add df2 columns in df1
I actually want the df1 column to be like this
df1 =

| carno | sales | jeepno | jsales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | 107 | 3 |
| 102 | 2 | 108 | 9 |
| 103 | 6 | nan | nan |
| 101 | 8 | nan | nan |

I tried below methed
`df1['jeepno'] = nan df1['jsales'] = nan`
I want to try using = method
`df1['jeepno'] = df2['jeepno'] df1['jsales'] = df2['jsales']`
the above method is working in python 3.10 but in my friends 3.6 its failing with error
"valueerror cannot reindex from a duplicate axis"

Pls assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to manually set columns with `nan`, just [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) dataframes columnwise with

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

---

```
   carno  sales  jeepno   jsales
0    101      1    107.0     3.0
1    102      2    108.0     9.0
2    103      6      NaN     NaN
3    101      8      NaN     NaN
```